# Condition on the normal field of two regular smooth curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

I have an example of two regular smooth curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ i.e $\alpha$ and $\beta$, such that

$$\beta(t) = \alpha(t) + \lambda \bf{N(t)}$$ and $$\text{prn}(\nabla_{\alpha'(t)}\bf{N}) = 0,$$
where $\bf{N}$ denotes the principal normal vector field along $\alpha$ and $prn$ 
denotes the orthogonal projection to the corresponding normal (vector) space 
of $\alpha$ and $\alpha'(t)$ is the tangent vector field, with $\lambda$ being a constant.

What does the above condition tell me exactly??The first one is quite clearly saying that $\beta$ is a translation of $\alpha$ along the normal to $\alpha$, but what about the second condition about the projection of the covariant derivative??

P.S. This is actually somewhat similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661144/condition-that-two-immersions-are-connected-by-a-parallel-section-of-their-norma

I would be grateful if this question can be answered in relation to the linked question,although even an independent answer would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct that if $\nabla$ is the obvious connection on the normal bundle of the curve, then $\mathbf N$ is a parallel normal field along $\alpha$. You don't say anything about $\lambda$; is it constant? I suspect that by looking at $\beta$, you're working with a ribbon that doesn't twist.

This also reminds me of Bertrand mates (but there $\mathbf N$ is the principal normal and the further stipulation is that it is also the principal normal of $\beta$). This construction can be made if and only if $\alpha$ is a curve so that $c_1\kappa + c_2\tau=1$ for some constants $c_1,c_2$.

**EDIT**: Perhaps this picture will help. On the left is the usual double helix, using the principal normal field. On the right is the "untwisted ribbon," using a parallel normal field.

[image: Ribbons]

Comment: Yes, $\lambda$ is a constant, I should have mentioned that. I am aware of Bertrand curves and I think in this context I can employ $\bf{N}$ as the principal normal, but it is the projection condition that was puzzling me. I will edit the question a bit

Comment: I did not understand why you said a ribbon $\textbf{without a twist}$, of course assuming $\lambda$ is not a constant in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those pictures, they clarify some things. But forgive me if I am missing something obvious here, what am I to make of the projection condition, $\text{prn} \nabla_{\alpha'(t)} \bf{N} = 0$? Also, in the general case for immersions given in the linked question, it can be proved that being connected by a parallel section of the normal bundles is equivalent to saying the normal spaces at each point of the immersions coincide. So in a way, this would give me Bertrand curves, but it may be that $\beta$'s binormal coincides with $\alpha$'s normal.

Comment: of course I am unable to provide a proof for that statement on immersions